Parsing error: ESLint was configured to run on `any file of mine` using `parserOptions.project` But only on my computer
I have fresh clone of my cypress repository where eslint gives me the following error problem and then stops working. The weird thing is that a collegue of mine does the same thing and does not get this error!!!:
Parsing error: ESLint was configured to run on `any file of mine` using `parserOptions.project`: <tsconfigRootDir>/tsconfig.json
However, that TSConfig does not include this file. Either:
- Change ESLint's list of included files to not include this file
- Change that TSConfig to include this file
- Create a new TSConfig that includes this file and include it in your parserOptions.project
See the typescript-eslint docs for more info: https://typescript-eslint.io/linting/troubleshooting#i-get-errors-telling-me-eslint-was-configured-to-run--however-that-tsconfig-does-not--none-of-those-tsconfigs-include-this-fileeslint

my .eslintrc.json looks like this at the relevant position:
"parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser",
  "parserOptions": {
    "project": "./tsconfig.json"
  },

and in my tsconfig.json is:
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "rootDir": "./",
    "baseUrl": "./cypress",
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext",
      "ESNext.Array",
    ],
    "types": [
      "cypress", "cypress-file-upload", "node"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "strict": true
  },
  "include": [
    "./cypress.config.ts",
    "cypress/**/*.ts",
    "**/*.ts"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "./.eslintrc.js"
  ],
}

Version of node: 20.18
Another collegue of mine with RHEL9.3 has the same problem with same ripository.
It seems like with RHEL8+ and windows, there is no problem. Node versions should be also out of question, as the RHEL9.3-collegue used even an older node (18).
